# Defining << operator at a base class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define the `<< operator` for a base class, so I can later print the identifier of each object easily.

I have tried an SSCCE, but I don't really know where the problem is, since I'm printing a direction and not the content. I don't know if the problem appears by printing the `vector` position, or by printing the `std::string(char[])`.

main.cpp:

```
#include "City.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<Location*> locations;
    locations.push_back(new City("TEST"));

    for(unsigned int it = 0; it<locations.size(); it++){
        std::cout << locations[it] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Location.h:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class Location {
public:
    Location(const std::string id);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Location& loc);
    std::string GetId();

private:
    // Name/identifier of the location
    char ID[5];
};
```

Location.cpp:

```
#include "Location.h"

Location::Location(const std::string id){
    memset(this->ID, 0, 5);
    strncpy(this->ID, id.c_str(), 5); // I have it as a char[5] at a larger app
}

std::string Location::GetId(){
    return std::string(this->ID);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Location& loc){
    os << loc.GetId();
    return os;
}
```

City.h:

```
#include "Location.h"

class City: public Location{
public:
    City(std::string id);
};
```

City.cpp:

```
#include "City.h"

City::City(const std::string id) : Location(id){

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The problem is not really with your operator function, it's that you store *pointers* in the vector, so you are printing the *pointer*. You have to *dereference* the pointer to make it work.

Comment: Oh, and you might have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your `GetId` member function, because the array `ID` might not be properly terminated as a string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I assumed it should be something as simple as that, thanks. I can accept that as an answer

Comment: did you try `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Location* loc){
    os << loc->GetId();
    return os;
}` or derefrence the pointers in vector before passing to cout as said in previous comments